# Why does infusing Witch Tree Branch with Faint Stone decrease it's ATK value?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I am very confused with how infusion works in Dark Souls 2. I have Witch Tree Branch +10 staff, when I tried to infuse it with faint stone the ATK value dropped by 3 points.

[image]

Why does that happen? If I use it for sorceries, does it worth infusing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens for nearly all infusions on all weapons. In one way or another stats or scaling is reduced.

In this particular case, it is reducing your physical attack value. Which does not affect casting sorceries.

Comment: @Hendry  if I have answered your question, don't forget to accept it by clicking on the "tick" icon to the left

Answer (score 2):

When you infuse a weapon, it reduces raw damage (Unless it is a Raw stone), and

reduces scaling grades(Any Stone). To make up for that, it adds a new type of

scaling/amplifies one, based on the type.

For example, a Faintstone adds magic damage, and scaling based on your

INT, but reduces other damage types, and other scaling types. **For the case of**

**you, you are reducing dark damage and increasing magic damage.**